# My MERN website keeps on telling me my one function is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am creating a MERN todo app that allows a user to add, edit and delete todo list items. I have created a modal form to appear when the user clicks on the update button on their todo item. I am currently just trying to get my function(updateNewToDo) to work which gets all the information from the children elements to update the DB. It seems to fail at the very last second and I dont understand why. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
The error I am getting when I press the update button in the modal is:

props.updateNewToDo is not a function

TypeError: props.updateNewToDo is not a function

```
Home.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import ToDoList from '../components/ToDoList';

const Home = () => {
    const [toDos, setToDos] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchToDos = async () => {
          const response = await fetch("/api/ToDo");
          const json = await response.json();

          if (response.ok) {
            setToDos(json);
          }
        };
        fetchToDos();
      }, []);

  //This is a function that will get the todo item that needs to be updated in the child components
      function updateNewToDo(id, Name){
        console.log("update the employee")
      }

  return (
    <div className='Home'>
        <div className='toDos'>
            {toDos && toDos.map((toDo) => <ToDoList key={toDo._id} props={toDo} id={toDo._id} updateNewToDo={updateNewToDo} />)}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home

ToDoList.js
import React from "react";
import EditToDo from "./EditToDo";

const ToDoList = ( {props} ) => {
  return (
    <div className="toDoList">
      <h4>To Do: </h4>
      <p>{props.Name}</p>
      <span>delete</span>
      <EditToDo Name={props.Name} updateNewToDo={props.updateNewToDo} id={props._id} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToDoList;

EditToDo.js
import { useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";

function EditToDo(props) {
  const [Name, setName] = useState(props.Name);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Update
      </Button>

      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Update To Do</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log('Hello from EditToDo');
              console.log(props.id, Name)
              props.updateNewToDo(props._id, Name);
            }}
            id="editModal"
            className="w-full max-w-sm"
          >
            <div className="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
              <div className="md:w-1/3">
                <label
                  className="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4"
                  for="name"
                >
                  To Do
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="md:w-2/3">
                <input
                  className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500"
                  id="name"
                  type="text"
                  value={Name}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setName(e.target.value);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <button
            onClick={handleClose}
            className="bg-slate-400 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded"
          >
            Close
          </button>

          <button
            form="editModal"
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded"
          >
            Update
          </button>


        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default EditToDo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the props of `<ToDoList>` component is named `props`, which creates the confusion and is the reason of your error.

Change the code of that component:

```
const ToDoList = ({
  props, // Actually the toDo item
  updateNewToDo // The prop with such name
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="toDoList">
      <h4>To Do: </h4>
      <p>{props.Name}</p>
      <span>delete</span>
      <EditToDo Name={props.Name} updateNewToDo={updateNewToDo /* Directly the prop variable */} id={props._id} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

By React convention, the first parameter of a Functional Component is indeed named `props`. It is an object which properties are the actual props.

But here you use a parameter destructuring (also common practice in React), so there is no reason to use that name.

You could rename that prop:

```
const ToDoList = ({
  toDo, // Actually the toDo item
  updateNewToDo // The prop with such name
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="toDoList">
      <h4>To Do: </h4>
      <p>{toDo.Name}</p>
      <span>delete</span>
      <EditToDo Name={toDo.Name} updateNewToDo={updateNewToDo /* Directly the prop variable */} id={toDo._id} />
    </div>
  );
};

// Usage:
<ToDoList
  key={toDo._id}
  toDo={toDo}
  updateNewToDo={updateNewToDo}
/>
```

Or avoid parameter destructuring:

```
const ToDoList = (props) => { // No parameter destructuring 
  return (
    <div className="toDoList">
      <h4>To Do: </h4>
      <p>{props.props.Name}</p>
      <span>delete</span>
      <EditToDo Name={props.props.Name} updateNewToDo={props.updateNewToDo} id={props.props._id} />
    </div>
  );
};
```